# решение задачи питон

Tags: python

В небольшой фруктовой лавке у каждого фрукта есть название и цена. Эта информация хранится в одном большом списке, вот так:

```
goods = [["яблоки", 50], ["апельсины", 190], ["груши", 100], ["нектарины", 200], ["бананы", 77]]
```

Недавно в лавку привезли новый `fruit_name` по цене `price`, а после этого случилось ужасное: повысили налоги. А значит, повысились и цены на фрукты, на целых 8%!

Реализуйте код, который добавляет в список `goods` ещё один список с новым фруктом и ценой (это запрашивается у пользователя), а затем увеличивает цены всех фруктов на 8%.

Пример:

Текущий ассортимент: `[["яблоки", 50], ["апельсины", 190], ["груши", 100], ["нектарины", 200], ["бананы", 77]]`

Новый фрукт: `абрикосы`

Цена: `150`

Новый ассортимент: `[["яблоки", 50], ["апельсины", 190], ["груши", 100], ["нектарины", 200], ["бананы", 77], ["абрикосы", 150]]`

Новый ассортимент с увел. ценой: `[['яблоки', 54.0], ['апельсины', 205.2], ['груши', 108.0], ['нектарины', 216.0], ['бананы', 83.16], ['абрикосы', 162.0]]`

я написал так

```
goods = [["яблоки", 50], ["апельсины", 190], ["груши", 100], ["нектарины", 200], ["бананы", 77]]
    
while True:    
    print('Ваш текущий список фруктов',goods)
      fruit_name=input('Новый фрукт: ')
      price=int(input('Цена: '))
      goods.append([fruit_name,price])
```

Подскажите как увеличить весь двумерный список на 8%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто:

```py
goods = [["яблоки", 50], ["апельсины", 190], ["груши", 100], ["нектарины", 200], ["бананы", 77]]

for item in goods:
    item[1] = round(item[1] * 1.08, 2)

print(goods)
```

Вывод:

```
[['яблоки', 54.0], ['апельсины', 205.2], ['груши', 108.0], ['нектарины', 216.0], ['бананы', 83.16]]
```

Comment: можете объяснить мне ?

Answer (score 1):

@Rezo Gavtadze оставил код с комментариями. Бесконечный цикл у вас в решении был лишним, поскольку в задании этого не просили. Из-за него каждый раз, когда вы вводите название нового фрукта и цену на него цикл повторяется и ввод начинается заново.

```
goods = [
    ["яблоки", 50],  # 0
    ["апельсины", 190],  # 1
    ["груши", 100],  # 2
    ["нектарины", 200],  # 3
    ["бананы", 77]  # 4
]

new_fruit = input()  # Пользователь вводит название нового фрукта
price = int(input())  # Пользователь вводит цену нового фрукта

# В вложенный список добавляем список, содержащий новый фрукт и его цену
goods.append([new_fruit, price])

# В переменную fruit на каждой итерации будет прилетать вложенный список
# На первую итерацию туда пойдет ["яблоки", 50]
# На вторую итерацию ["апельсины", 190] и т.д.
# Соответственно, к этому вложенному списку мы можем обратиться fruit[0] -> "апельсины"
for fruit in goods:
    fruit[1] = round(fruit[1] * 1.08, 2)

# Встроенная функция round принимает два аргумента - число, которое нужно округлить и до скольки знаков
# То есть round(86.270) -> 86.27
# По факту, в задании не написано до скольки знаков округлять, поэтому можете писать просто round()


print(goods)
```

Comment: огромное спасибо